# Input string was not in a correct format when converting value from database into integer

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem in converting string from database to integer.

When I look at Locals, that variable show the value but notification still says that there is something wrong. Anyone can help me?

```
OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
OleDbCommand command1 = kon.CreateCommand();

kon.Open();
string selectkoordgaris = "select * from koordinatgaris where namakamera = '" + PilihKameraComboBox.Text + "'";
command1.CommandText = selectkoordgaris;
OleDbDataReader bacakoordgaris = command1.ExecuteReader();   

while (bacakoordgaris.Read())
  {        
    var templateGaris = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Dokumen\Alfon\TA Alfon\CobaFitur\Template\Garis\" + bacakoord["namakamera"].ToString());

foreach (var fileGaris in templateGaris)
 {
    counterbanyakgaris++;
    Image<Bgr, byte> garis = new Image<Bgr, byte>(fileGaris);

    for (cntgaris = 0; cntgaris < banyakgaris; cntgaris++)
     {
      int x1garis = int.Parse(bacakoordgaris["x" + ((cntgaris * 4) + 1) + "garis"].ToString()); //here the error. It says Input string was not in a correct format
      int x2garis = int.Parse(bacakoordgaris["x" + ((cntgaris * 4) + 2) + "garis"].ToString());
      int y1garis = int.Parse(bacakoordgaris["y" + ((cntgaris * 4) + 1) + "garis"].ToString());
      int y2garis = int.Parse(bacakoordgaris["y" + ((cntgaris * 4) + 2) + "garis"].ToString());
      int y3garis = int.Parse(bacakoordgaris["y" + ((cntgaris * 4) + 3) + "garis"].ToString());

      int gariswidth = x2garis - x1garis;
      int garisheight = y3garis - y2garis;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are x and y columns in your database table? The correct way to get data from a column in table is bacakoordgaris["columnName"].ToString()

Comment: Have you evaluated `bacakoordgaris["x" + ((cntgaris * 4) + 1) + "garis"]` to see what it returns?

Comment: Yes @Kami. x and y are columns in my DB table. So here, I want to get value from each x and y columns depend on value of cntgaris. When my cntgaris is 0, then my x1garis value is got from x1garis column, x2garis from x2garis, etc. When my cntgaris is 1, then my x1garis value is got from x5garis, my x2garis from x6garis, etc

Comment: Yes I have @dustmouse. I have set Toogle Breakpoint to know value of each variables. It can show value of each variables but error still exists

Comment: @Kami. I can't use it. It says Operator "+" cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'. Can you help me ?

Comment: Try this one. I noticed a mistake in my earlier post. int x1garis = int.Parse(bacakoordgaris["x"]) + ((cntgaris * 4) + 1) + garis;

Comment: It is assumed that x and y are not null!

Comment: @Kami. It's the same. I can't use it.

Comment: @Kami. Actually I set my columns to be not null. Is it wrong ? Please help me

Comment: are you still getting the same error? Put a breakpoint in your for loop and watch the value of bacakoorgaris["x"].  Finally instead of int.parse use Convert.ToInt16.

Comment: @Kami. I have tried to use your recommend code and it still getting error. It says that your code has some valid arguments. By the way garis is not variable. It's just name of my columns. Changing only the cntgaris. So I can say like this x(cntgaris)garis.

Comment: You are defining garis in your foreach loop as a variable, that's why I thought it's not in the database.  try int x1garis = Convert.ToInt16(bacakoordgaris["x"]) + ((cntgaris * 4) + 1) + Convert.ToInt16(bacakoordgaris["garis"]);

Comment: I am sorry for making you confused. Hehehe. I have tried your code and it is getting some error. It says IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled, and the Message is x. I think it can't read my data column name

Comment: can you share your table definition?

Comment: @Kami. string selectkoordgaris = "select * from koordinatgaris where namakamera = '" + PilihKameraComboBox.Text + "'";

I select koordinatgaris table

Comment: This is a select statement not a table definition!

Comment: I am sorry. Hehehe. 

Field Size : Integer
Default Value : 0
Required : Yes
Indexed : No

Are they true ?

Comment: what about the garis column?

Comment: So here I have x1garis, x2garis, x3 garis, x4garis, until x50garis and y1garis until y50garis columns. Each columns have the same definition

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: What does crazy-vulnerable mean ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the output of `bacakoordgaris["x" + ((cntgaris * 4) + 1) + "garis"]` is not in a numeric format (it may contains some string in it).

You can add `breakpoint` to that line and add watch to check the returned value from `bacakoordgaris["x" + ((cntgaris * 4) + 1) + "garis"]` and correct it before parsing it to integer (by String.Replace() method for example).

Comment: I am sorry @idealidea, I am newbie :( . Can you lead me to do that ? I do not exactly understand about it.

Comment: So you need to learn how to debug programs. [Here I found a good article about how to use breakpoints in C#](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s5p4.html). You can find more tutorials and details about debugging tools from google.